# Presenting Modal After Form Submission in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to create a modal that will tell the user their submission was successfully submitted. This works fairly well, but the only problem is I have to declare each of my properties and assign it a value, then in the Json method I have accept all those parameters then do something with them. Is there any way to do this with a ViewModel? Or any otherway that this can be done using a ViewModel?

controller:

```
public Json Send(string var1, string var2)
{
   ...
   if(valid)
       return new Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   else
       return new Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

javascript:

```
function submitData() {
    $.ajax({
                       url: "/Report/Send",
                       type: "POST",
                       dataType: "json",
                       data: { var1 = Model.var1, var2 = Model.var2... },
                       success: function (data) {
                           if(data) {
                               showDialog();
                           }
                           else {
                               $("#errorDiv").load('Report/Error/');
                           }
                       },
                           error: function (somefunction) { }
                       });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a ViewModel POCO class:

```
var myJsonResult = new { result: true };
return Json(myJsonResult);
```

You can also use a strongly typed ViewModel and return that:

```
var myJsonResult = new CustomResult { result: true };
return Json(myJsonResult);
```

Then just check that property on the class in your success function:

```
success: function (data) {
                           if(data.result) {
                               showDialog();
                           }
                           else if(!data.result) {
                               $("#errorDiv").load('Report/Error/');
                           }
                       },
```

EDIT:

You might also want to look at jquery's [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method:

```
data:  $("#myForm").serialize()
```

This will be useful if you bind your ViewModel to form elements and need to post them back to the server.

Comment: Is possible to submit a viewmodel to JSON method using the data attribute?

Comment: I don't understand you question, can you expand on that?